# Functors - Import type

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to OCaml, and trying to learn about functors. So far, I have the following:

```
utop # module type Foo = sig
  type t = {
      foo : int;
      bar : int;
  }
  val create : int -> int -> t
  val get : t -> int
end;;

utop # module FooImpl = struct
  type t = {
      foo : int;
      bar : int;
  }
  let create x y = {
      foo = x;
      bar = y;
  }
  let get w = w.foo
end;;
```

Now I'll try to define my functor, which will operate on modules of type Foo and replace the `get` function.

```
utop # module Functor (F : Foo) : Foo with type t := F.t = struct
  let create = F.create
  let get w = w.bar
end;;
Error: Unbound record field bar
```

It doesn't know about the type of the record. I'll try defining it:

```
utop # module Functor (F : Foo) : Foo with type t := F.t = struct
  type t = {
      foo : int;
      bar : int;
  }
  let create = F.create
  let get w = w.bar
end;;
Error: Signature mismatch:                                                                                                                ...                                                                                                                                Values do not match:
     val get : t -> int
   is not included in
     val get : F.t -> int
```

So OCaml doesn't know that `t` and `F.t` are actually the same type. So I'll try saying that:

```
utop # module Functor (F : Foo) : Foo with type t := F.t = struct
  type t = F.t
  let create = F.create
  let get w = w.bar
end;;
Error: Unbound record field bar
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field names belong to a scope of a module where they are defined. For example, if you define a record in module `Foo`

```
module Foo = struct
  type t = { bar : int; baz : int; quz : int }
end
```

Then in order to access this fields outside of the module `Foo` you need to use a fully qualified name, e.g.,

```
let bar_of_foo x = x.Foo.bar
```

In pattern matching field names may be also qualified, this allows to write the above function as follows:

```
let bar_of_foo {Foo.bar} = bar
```

You need to qualify only one name, so this syntax is useful, when you need to access several fields at once:

```
let sum_of_foo {Foo.bar; baz; quz} = bar + baz + quz
```

Finally, you can `open` module to bring the record names to the current scope. You can use local open syntax `Foo.(expr)` to localize the impact of opening:

```
 let bar_of_foo x = Foo.(x.bar)
```

In your example fields are defined in module `F` that is a parameter to a functor `Functor`. So, you need to use one of the above methods to access it fields, e.g.,

```
module Functor (F : Foo) : Foo with type t := F.t = struct
 open F
 let create = F.create
 let get w = w.bar
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt at defining Functor works for me if I define `get` like this:

```
let get w = w.F.bar
```

Here's my full session:

```
# module type Foo = sig (... ELIDED...) end;;
module type Foo =
  sig
    type t = { foo : int; bar : int; }
    val create : int -> int -> t
    val get : t -> int
  end
# module FooImpl = struct (...ELIDED...) end;;
module FooImpl :
  sig
    type t = { foo : int; bar : int; }
    val create : int -> int -> t 
    val get : t -> int
  end
# module Functor (F: Foo) : Foo with type t := F.t = struct 
    let create = F.create 
    let get w = w.F.bar 
end;;
module Functor :
  functor (F : Foo) ->
    sig val create : int -> int -> F.t val get : F.t -> int end
# module F2 = Functor(FooImpl);;
module F2 :
  sig val create : int -> int -> FooImpl.t val get : FooImpl.t -> int end
# let c1 = FooImpl.create 8 9;;
val c1 : FooImpl.t = {FooImpl.foo = 8; bar = 9}
# FooImpl.get c1;;
- : int = 8
# let c2 = F2.create 8 9;;
val c2 : FooImpl.t = {FooImpl.foo = 8; bar = 9}
# F2.get c2;;
- : int = 9
```